# What are the things to pass in the GET request with user-agent in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, request, user-agent

I am trying to scrape the https://www.boscovs.com/ website. Boscovs development team shared bot name with us. If I add the bot name in the header like

```
headers = {"User-Agent": 'Name Given by the dev team/1.0'}
data = requests.get('https://www.boscovs.com/', headers=headers)
```

I am getting timeout error but if we I random string like sample, test, custom, etc...

```
headers = {"User-Agent": 'sample'}
data = requests.get('https://www.boscovs.com/', headers=headers)
```

I am getting the 200 as response. But If I pass the valid bot name with the URL, it throws timeout error. I don't know why it's happening it's blocking the bot alone. What I have to pass with the bot name. Can you help me to solve this. Ultimately I have to use the bot name given by them.

Comment: This seems like a query that you need to check with the respective dev team. Also, check if you have to pass any authorization token along with the request.

Comment: They are telling me to search on Google...!